# VBA - unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the error "unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class". An inputBox asks the user to enter a model number, then a status, either "2" or "3" for retail or educational pricing, vLookup is supposed to look up the price dependent on what the user entered. A5:A15 is Model #'s, B5:B15 is retail pricing, C5:C15 is educational pricing. **PriceList range is A5:A15**

```
Dim strModel As String
Dim strStatus As String
Dim shtComputers As Worksheet
Dim curPrice As Currency


Set shtComputers = Application.Workbooks("T6-EX- 
E3D.xlsm").Worksheets("computers")

shtComputers.Unprotect

strModel = InputBox("Enter Model #: ", Default:="C100")

strStatus = InputBox("Enter status, 2 for retail or 3 for educational: ", Default:="2")

Range("Model") = strModel

Range("Status") = strStatus

curPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strModel,Range("PriceList"), strStatus, False)

Range("Price").Value = curPrice
```

Comment: pricelist range should be A5:C15.

Comment: @ScottCraner, that worked, simple mistake, thanks!